# Read and set a variable on the Windows command line from a .json file

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have this little **config.json**:

```
{
    "version":"0.2.2",
    "test":true
}
```

I'd like to read this file and set variables in the window command line corresponding the keys and values from the `json` file, perhaps something like this pseudo code:

```
for /f %%A in (config.json) do (

    SET key = value
)

echo %VERSION%
echo %TEST%
```

**How would I do that?**

Comment: Show the exact data values you expect in the output, as your data formats are not the same.

Comment: I expect the output to be: `0.2.2` and `true`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solves the question as posed:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set c=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:, " %%a in (' find ":" ^< "config.json" ') do (
   set /a c+=1
   set val[!c!]=%%~a
)
for /L %%b in (1,1,!c!) do echo !val[%%b]!
pause
```

This version will output `version = 0.2.2` and `test = true`
The only change is in line 6

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set c=0
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:, " %%a in (' find ":" ^< "config.json" ') do (
   set /a c+=1
   set val[!c!]=%%~a = %%~b
)
for /L %%b in (1,1,!c!) do echo !val[%%b]!
pause
```

This solves the next format request: variable-name=value

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:, " %%a in (' find ":" ^< "config.json" ') do (
   set "%%~a=%%~b"
)
set
pause
```

**The request from Feb 2016** can be solved with this, assuming the file looks like below:

```
 {
 location : "C:\\Test Folder"
 }
```

Batch script below

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in (' find ":" ^< "config.json" ') do echo "%%~c"
pause
```

Comment: Just a question though, if I'd like to output the following: `version = 0.2.2` and `test = true`, how would I do that?

Comment: I see. I hate to be a burden but what if I'd like to create variables named after the keys and set to to values of the keys n the `json` file?

Comment: This is the answer to my last question, right? set "%%~a=%%~b"

Comment: What if the property value has spaces in it?  Doesn't seem to work in that case.  Something like { location : "C:\\Test Folder" } will echo "location = C" with this code.

Comment: @ariestav I've added code - I'm not sure what format you want the output in so left it simple.